# las imágenes del slider de mi pagina en html no funcionan correctamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css

```js
$(function(){
  $("#slideshow").slidesjs();
});
```

```css
@import url ('reset.css');
@import url ('fuentes.css');

/*---Estilos Generales ------------*/
body {
  background: #2d2d2d;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
}
  a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}

/*---Header ---*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfeff 47%, #e4e0e0 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfeff 47%,#e4e0e0 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#fcfeff 47%,#e4e0e0 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e4e0e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
copy
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;

}

#subheader{
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logotipo{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 0px
}

#logotipo a{
  font-family: sourcesans-light;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
}

#logotipo a:hover {text-decoration:none;}

/*Menu*/
header #subheader nav{
  float: left;
  width: 660px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

header #subheader nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: sourcesans;
}
header #subheader nav ul li a{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

}
header #subheader nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1798af;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*---Main---*/

#main {
  width: 100%;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
}

/*slideshow*/

#slideshow{
  width: 920px;
  height: 260px;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  border: solid 20px #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slidesjs-next.slidesjs-navigation {
 visibility: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.slidesjs-previous.slidesjs-navigation {
 visibility: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination {
 margin: -16px auto;
 width: 100px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 5px;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
 display: block;
 width: 12px;
 height: 0px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li .active {
 background-color: #1798af;
}

#slideshow img {
 width: 920px;
 height: 260px;
}





/*---bienvenidos---*/
#Bienvenidos{
  width: 920px;
  float:left;
  padding: 20px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#46793a+0,46793a+47,2d4c1e+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #46793a 0%, #46793a 47%, #2d4c1e 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #46793a 0%,#46793a 47%,#2d4c1e 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #46793a 0%,#46793a 47%,#2d4c1e 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#46793a', endColorstr='#2d4c1e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin:20px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
}

#bienvenidos article h3 {
  font-family: :sourcesans-light;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#bienvenidos article {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 27px;
}

/*--contenido--*/
 #contenido{
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
 }

 #contenido article{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

 }

 #contenido article .titulo{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: sourcesans;
  color: #fff;

 }

 #contenido article .fecha{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#1798af;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 #contenido article .thumb{
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;

 }

 #contenido article > p {
  color:#8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
 }

 /*--sidebar---*/
 aside {
  width: 220px;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #4d78b3;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;


 }

 aside .widget {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float:left;
 }

 aside .widget >h3 {
  background:#fff;
  color: #4d78b3;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside .widget a  {color: #fff;}
 aside .widget ul li {margin-bottom: 5px;}
 aside .widget img {width:220px;}

 /*footer*/

 footer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2f2f2f+0,2f2f2f+47,242424+100 */
background: #2f2f2f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2f2f 0%, #2f2f2f 47%, #242424 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2f2f 0%,#2f2f2f 47%,#242424 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2f2f2f 0%,#2f2f2f 47%,#242424 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f2f2f', endColorstr='#242424',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

 }
 footer section{
  width:440px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
 }
footer #acerca-de {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica,Sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8c8c8c;

 }
 footer#acerca-de h3{
  font-family: sourcesans-light;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 footer #redes-s > div {
  width: 220px;
  height:60;
  float:left;
  background: #ff8000;
  opacity: :0.7;
 }
 footer #reders-s >div a{
  width:220px;
  height:60px;
  display: inline-block;

 }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidesjs/3.0/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div id="subheader">
   <div id="logotipo"><p><a href="">SISE</a></p></div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Pagina de Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contenidos Digitales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div>
 </header>

 <section id ="wrap">
  <section id ="main">
    <section id="slideshow">

        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/slideshows/inv3.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/slideshows/inv4.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/slideshows/inv4.jpg"></a>




    </section>
    <section id="Bienvenidos">
       <article>
        <hgroup><h3>Bienvenido a nuestro sitio web</h3></hgroup>
        <p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Integer ac ante vestibulum, vehicula tortor in, placerat ex.</li>
            <li>Sed id tellus ultricies, feugiat massa eget, viverra mi.</li>
            <li>Integer ac quam ut nulla consequat facilisis.</li>
            <li>Vivamus at augue sed tortor placerat blandit.</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
       </article>
       </section>
  </section>
  <section id="contenido">
    <article>
      <hgroup><h2 class="titulo">Titulo del articulo</h2></hgroup>
      <p class="fecha">07 de marzo del 2017</p>
      <img class="thumb" src="imagenes/inv1.jpg" alt="Thumbail #1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <hgroup><h2 class="titulo">Titulo del articulo</h2></hgroup>
      <p class="fecha">07 de marzo del 2017</p>
      <img class="thumb" src="imagenes/inv1.jpg" alt="Thumbail #1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <aside>
    <section class="widget">
      <h3>Articulos Recomendados</h3>
      <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
      </ul>
      </section>

      <section class="widget">
      <h3>Articulos Recientes</h3>
      <img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" width="220px">
      </section>

  </aside>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <section id="acerca-de">
      <article>
        <hgroup><h3>Acerca de ...</h3></hgroup>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section id="redes-s">
      <div class="email"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="twitter"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="youtube"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
    </section>
  </footer>

  <div id="copyright"><p>dcjwlcnkwcwhbvkwcwkejcnwkjecwek</p></div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Errores:

1.- Al crear el `slidesjs`, no has indicado el `width` ni el `height`, [opciones **requeridas**](http://www.slidesjs.com/)

2.- Los estilos creados para la clase `slidesjs-pagination` y sus distintas partes provocan que no se vean.

### Soluciones:

1.- Crear el `slidesjs` indicando el `width` y el `height`.

2.- Modificar los estilos para la clase `slidesjs-pagination` y sus distintas partes para que se vean.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#slideshow").slidesjs({
    width: 920,
    height: 260
  });
});
```

```css
@import url ('reset.css');
@import url ('fuentes.css');

/*---Estilos Generales ---*/
body {
  background: #2d2d2d;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
}
  a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}

/*---Header ---*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfeff 47%, #e4e0e0 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfeff 47%,#e4e0e0 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#fcfeff 47%,#e4e0e0 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e4e0e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
copy
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;

}

#subheader{
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logotipo{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 0px
}

#logotipo a{
  font-family: sourcesans-light;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
}

#logotipo a:hover {text-decoration:none;}

/*Menu*/
header #subheader nav{
  float: left;
  width: 660px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

header #subheader nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: sourcesans;
}
header #subheader nav ul li a{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

}
header #subheader nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1798af;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*---Main---*/

#main {
  width: 100%;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
}

/*slideshow*/

#slideshow{
  width: 920px;
  height: 260px;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  border: solid 20px #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slidesjs-next.slidesjs-navigation {
 visibility: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.slidesjs-previous.slidesjs-navigation {
 visibility: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination {
 margin: -15px auto 0;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 5px;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 6px;
 background-color: #a6af17;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
 display: block;
 width: 12px;
 height: 0px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li .active {
 background-color: #1798af;
}

#slideshow img {
 width: 920px;
 height: 260px;
}





/*---bienvenidos---*/
#Bienvenidos{
  width: 920px;
  float:left;
  padding: 20px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#46793a+0,46793a+47,2d4c1e+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #46793a 0%, #46793a 47%, #2d4c1e 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #46793a 0%,#46793a 47%,#2d4c1e 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #46793a 0%,#46793a 47%,#2d4c1e 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#46793a', endColorstr='#2d4c1e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin:20px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
}

#bienvenidos article h3 {
  font-family: :sourcesans-light;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#bienvenidos article {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 27px;
}

/*--contenido--*/
 #contenido{
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
 }

 #contenido article{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

 }

 #contenido article .titulo{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: sourcesans;
  color: #fff;

 }

 #contenido article .fecha{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#1798af;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 #contenido article .thumb{
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;

 }

 #contenido article > p {
  color:#8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
 }

 /*--sidebar---*/
 aside {
  width: 220px;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #4d78b3;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;


 }

 aside .widget {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float:left;
 }

 aside .widget >h3 {
  background:#fff;
  color: #4d78b3;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside .widget a  {color: #fff;}
 aside .widget ul li {margin-bottom: 5px;}
 aside .widget img {width:220px;}

 /*footer*/

 footer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2f2f2f+0,2f2f2f+47,242424+100 */
background: #2f2f2f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2f2f 0%, #2f2f2f 47%, #242424 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2f2f 0%,#2f2f2f 47%,#242424 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2f2f2f 0%,#2f2f2f 47%,#242424 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f2f2f', endColorstr='#242424',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

 }
 footer section{
  width:440px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
 }
footer #acerca-de {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica,Sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8c8c8c;

 }
 footer#acerca-de h3{
  font-family: sourcesans-light;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 footer #redes-s > div {
  width: 220px;
  height:60;
  float:left;
  background: #ff8000;
  opacity: :0.7;
 }
 footer #reders-s >div a{
  width:220px;
  height:60px;
  display: inline-block;

 }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidesjs/3.0/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div id="subheader">
   <div id="logotipo"><p><a href="">SISE</a></p></div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Pagina de Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contenidos Digitales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div>
 </header>

 <section id ="wrap">
  <section id ="main">
    <section id="slideshow">

        <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/920x260"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/920x260"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/920x260"></a>




    </section>
    <section id="Bienvenidos">
       <article>
        <hgroup><h3>Bienvenido a nuestro sitio web</h3></hgroup>
        <p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Integer ac ante vestibulum, vehicula tortor in, placerat ex.</li>
            <li>Sed id tellus ultricies, feugiat massa eget, viverra mi.</li>
            <li>Integer ac quam ut nulla consequat facilisis.</li>
            <li>Vivamus at augue sed tortor placerat blandit.</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
       </article>
       </section>
  </section>
  <section id="contenido">
    <article>
      <hgroup><h2 class="titulo">Titulo del articulo</h2></hgroup>
      <p class="fecha">07 de marzo del 2017</p>
      <img class="thumb" src="imagenes/inv1.jpg" alt="Thumbail #1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <hgroup><h2 class="titulo">Titulo del articulo</h2></hgroup>
      <p class="fecha">07 de marzo del 2017</p>
      <img class="thumb" src="imagenes/inv1.jpg" alt="Thumbail #1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <aside>
    <section class="widget">
      <h3>Articulos Recomendados</h3>
      <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
      </ul>
      </section>

      <section class="widget">
      <h3>Articulos Recientes</h3>
      <img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" width="220px">
      </section>

  </aside>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <section id="acerca-de">
      <article>
        <hgroup><h3>Acerca de ...</h3></hgroup>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section id="redes-s">
      <div class="email"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="twitter"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="youtube"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
      <div class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></article></div>
    </section>
  </footer>

  <div id="copyright"><p>dcjwlcnkwcwhbvkwcwkejcnwkjecwek</p></div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que quieres que se mueva solo ¿no?, te falto una linea de codigo:

```
$(function(){
  $("#slideshow").slidesjs({
    width: 700,
    height: 393,
    navigation: false,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 1000,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      restartDelay: 2500
    }
  });
});
```

Te dejo el fiddle funcionando [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/g6mqd78x/).
Suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda pero creo que no me hice entender bien, el problema es que las imagenes del slider quedan por fuera del div y lo que necesito es que no se vean